# Determining $ \int\sqrt{\frac{x^4-8x^2+16}{16x^2}+1}\;dx $

Tags: calculus

I'm attempting to find the antiderivative of the following function,
$$
\int\sqrt{\dfrac{x^4-8x^2+16}{16x^2}+1}\;dx
$$

However, I can't seem to find an easier, equivalent function to make integration easier. A calculator says that

$$
\frac{1}{4}∫\dfrac{x^2+4}{x} dx
$$

is equivalent to the first function, but I am unsure how to reach this simpler form from the first function. Any help with reaching this second function would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bringing the $1$ into the fraction gives:

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^4 - 8x^2 + 16 + 16x^2}{16x^2}}dx = \int \sqrt {\frac{x^4 + 8x^2 +16}{16x^2}}dx = \int \sqrt{\frac{(x^2 + 4)^2}{16x^2}}dx.$$

Which (assuming $x \ne 0 $) then clearly simplifies to:

> $$\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{x^2 + 4}{|x|}dx.$$

Comment: $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It depends on how it's defined surely. Considering it was basic algebraic manipulation the OP needed help with, that seems like a pretty minor gripe from you, and also over complicating the Q

Comment: Still, please adjust the denominator to be always positive, assuming it is not zero.

Comment: @dan_fulea done